# Proper capitalization of the term "software as a service"

Tags: blog, terminology, capitalization

I need to use the term "software as a service", which is abbreviated as SaaS. (There are other ancillary terms as well like Platform as a Service, Functions as a Service, Infrastructure as a Service and so many more.)

Is there an industry-wide agreed upon consensus to capitalize/hyphenate these when you spell them out? I don't see anything definitive. (And my company style guide unfortunately doesn't have an opinion, which is funny since we're a SaaS company! LOL.)

So far in my searching I've found:

- software as a service
- Software as a Service
- Software-as-a-Service

Some further context I can provide is that I wrote it as "software as a service" in some copy. This fits our style guide in that we only capitalize product names, not features or attributes of products. I'm being corrected to use "Software as a Service", though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct form is "software as a service."  It is simply a phrase that describes the software.

Some people (incorrectly) do things like "Software as a Service" - it seems they "work backwards" from the abbreviated form (SaaS) and use the capitalization from the abbreviated form when spelling it out.

As the title of a section in a document, the regular capitalization rules would apply.  Say you have a page titled "Understanding Software as a Service" - that would be capitalized as shown.

---

Marketroids randomly capitalize everything to "make it look more important."  It's wrong, but that's marketing.

Comment: I'm going to adopt regular use of "marketroids" going forward (even thought it wasn't one of them who provided this feedback).

Answer (score 1):

“SaaS” or “Software as a Service” is the correct recognized way of capitalizing, due to the focus on meaningful words and leaving behind the things leading to then. In programming, this is a common practice.

If you are looking for the correctness of the term in reality, SaaS is incorrect, as it doesn't denote the actual thing. [As explained by Richard Stallman](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/who-does-that-server-really-serve.html), "SaaS" is more accurately described as "Service as a Software Substitute" (SaaSS), - using a service as a substitute for running your copy of a program, where you're getting something you should've already had in the first place.

**SaaSS** is closer to the truth, where **SaaS** is closer to what's common. In any case, it's not *saas* or *Saas*, that's for sure.